# Using asynchronous functions in try block

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, puppeteer

I have a puppeteer program, in which I have to call `page.waitForSelector`, which is an asynchronous function, to see if it throws any errors. But I assume, because a try-block is synchronous and it doesn't wait for an asynchronous function to be finished, even when I use `await`, it continues Executing the code after the try-block before even checking if there's an error. This is my code:

```
try {
    await page.waitForSelector("#captchaImage", {timeout: 6000});
}
catch {
    console.log("Your URL has changed");
    return;
}
console.log("You're still on the good site :)");
```

Is there a way to fix this problem or to make an asynchronous function synchronous (So it blocks code execution)?

Comment: `page.waitForSelector` must return a Promise (otherwise you couldn't `await` it), so why not just use the built-in [catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method rather than a try/catch which, as you note, is designed for synchronous code, not async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be asynchronous a function must return a `Promise`. Then it's possible to attach handlers like `.then()` or `.catch()` to handle return value when `Promise` is resolved or rejected, respectively. Another way of handling asynchronous actions is to `await` them and make current block of code to wait until the `Promise` is settled.

The first thing you have to do is to check if `waitForSelector` returns a Promise. It can return `Promise` explicitly in its return statement, or you can use `async` keyword in function definition to wrap the return value in the `Promise`:

```
async function waitForSelector(param1, param2) {
  // code goes here
  return result;
}
```

Then you can either attach `.then()` `.catch()` handlers or use `await` keyword to wait for result synchronously.

```
try {
    // assuming that it returns some value you want to process when function finishes
    let result = await page.waitForSelector("#captchaImage", {timeout: 6000});
    console.log(result);
}
catch {
    console.log("Your URL has changed");
    return;
}
console.log("You're still on the good site :)");
```

­

Note, that you cannot `await` a function in global scope, outside of a function. It means that your above code must be either placed inside another `async` function or wrapped in IIFE like given below:

```
(function() {
  //above code goes here
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't even know this function exists! :)

Comment: I updated my answer with important note about where you're allowed to use `await` keyword. It's a common pitfall to use it in global context where it won't work.